# Draw on cmd using c++

Tags: c++, winapi, cmd

I'm trying to draw a chess board on the cmd screen - 64 squares, and a letter in each one, that symbolize the solider that in this place.
After very long searching, I found a code that change the words color, but my question is how can I draw squares on the cmd? BLACK - WHITE and so on.
This is the code I've found :

```
int main()
{

    HANDLE hConsole;
    hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    // Use the three primary colors for mixing any other color.
    // Use FOREGROUND_INTENSITY for brighter colors.
    SetConsoleTextAttribute
        (hConsole, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    cout << "Bright red text\n";

    SetConsoleTextAttribute
        (hConsole, FOREGROUND_BLUE | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    cout << "Bright blue text\n";

    SetConsoleTextAttribute
        (hConsole, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE);
    cout << "Back to normal white text\n";

    // Wait for user pressing key before exiting
    // Gives them a chance to see the output
    cout << "\n\nPress any key to exit program.....";
    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

I'll be glad for some help.

Answer (score 2):

since white is red+green+blue:  background white is

```
BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_BLUE
```

in code:

```
SetConsoleTextAttribute
    (hConsole,BACKGROUND_RED | BACKGROUND_GREEN | BACKGROUND_BLUE )
cout << "black on white\n";
```

Comment: And how can I make it bigger with different colors?
For example 10X10 square with 'K' in the middle of it, and next-to it a black rectangle with 'P' in the middle of it?

Comment: print 10 characters, then on the next line 10 more etc..  BTW doing twice as many characters across as rows down  usuall gets close to square as most console fonts are twice as high as they are wide.

Answer (score 1):

Someone did this on [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/242879/Cplusplus-Drawing-Rectangles-to-Console) (Draw rectangle on screen):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

using std::cout;

/*
 *This method sets the cursor position.
 *Usage:
 *setxy(1,1);
 */
BOOL setxy(short x, short y)
{
    COORD c = {x,y};
    return SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),c);
}

/*
 *This method draws the rectangle.
 *Usage:
 *DrawRect(1,1,10,10);
 *or
 *DrawRect(1,1,10,10,20,5);
 */
void DrawRect(int x, int y, int width, int height, int curPosX=0, int curPosY=0)
{
    setxy(x,y);cout << char(201);
    for(int i = 1; i < width; i++)cout << char(205);
    cout << char(187);
    setxy(x,height + y);cout << char(200);
    for(int i = 1; i < width; i++)cout << char(205);
    cout << char(188);
    for(int i = y + 1; i < height + y; i++)
    {
        setxy(x,i);cout << char(186);
        setxy(x + width,i);cout << char(186);
    }
    setxy(curPosX,curPosY);
}

int main()
{
    setxy(1,1);
    DrawRect(1,1,10,10,20,5);
    return 0;
}
```

Hope it helps

Comment: I saw this one, but it doesn't help me because I want to write a letter in the middle of the rectangle. Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You have found the code, but you didn't really bother to understand it or to look at the documentation for `SetConsoleTextAttribute`.

If you had, you'd have discovered the documentation about [character attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682088(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_character_attributes) and noticed things like `BACKGROUND_RED`, `BACKGROUND_GREEN` and `BACKGROUND_BLUE` which, predictably, can set the background color in the console.

Now, with the ability to change the color of the background, ask yourself "what happens if I set the background color to `FOREGROUND_RED` and *then* print a space on the console?"

Answer (score 0):

```
    //win api  drawing
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

void draw(HWND hwnd, HDC hdc);
void setConsoleSize();
void main()
{
  SetConsoleTitle(L"Simple Rectangle Drawing");
  HWND hwnd = GetConsoleWindow();
  HDC hdc = GetDC(hwnd);
  setConsoleSize(); // set console size
  Sleep(100);
  draw(hwnd, hdc); // drawing function
  int iKey = 1;
  while (iKey != 27) { // exit on ESC key
    if (_kbhit()) {
    iKey = _getch();
    switch (iKey)
      {
      case 112: case 80: case 167: case 135:
      draw(hwnd, hdc); // on   key 'p' we redraw
      break;
      }
    }
  }
  ReleaseDC(hwnd, hdc); //cleaning console descriptors
}

// here you place your Drawing
void draw(HWND hwnd, HDC hdc)
{
  Rectangle(hdc, 100, 60, 180, 160); // example
}

void setConsoleSize() 
{
  const int colConsole = 80;
  const int rowConsole = 30;
  HANDLE hNdl = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
  SMALL_RECT windowSize ={0,0,colConsole-1,rowConsole-1};
  SetConsoleWindowInfo(hNdl, TRUE, &windowSize);// bufferSize 
  SetConsoleScreenBufferSize(hNdl, bufferSize);
}
```